# Physics Ph.D. Prospect

Tags: phd, career-path, physics

I am a physics undergraduate student in Asia. In the past, I planned to apply for graduate school once I finished my undergraduate. However, nowadays, I'm starting to have doubts about that plan. One reason is that I am worried about my future career. Another reason is that I'm not sure whether I can endure graduate school or not (My original plan is to enroll in an American graduate school).

I do like physics and am eager to learn more. It's just that I'm unsure whether I should choose the career path of academia or industry and whether I should continue to graduate school or not.

Please give me your thoughts/knowledge on this matter. It will be really helpful for me.

Comment: This is too personal for an answer here. You would do better to consult a local source. One of your current professors might be a good choice. You might also look at what industry options are open to you and what life there would be like. But the value system is yours.

Comment: @Buffy What do you think about getting a Ph.D. and working in the industry? Is it overkill? Will a bachelor's degree be enough for industry?

Comment: It depends on the industry job you want. Start by looking at job descriptions for companies and positions you would be interested in having in the next 5-10 years. See what the education requirements are.

Comment: The world is your oyster. The question is super unspecific and depends on individual factors a lot. VTC. I would suggest looking up questions about industry vs academia career tracks here and doing some reading first.

Answer (score 1):

Graduate school is not for everyone. That's not meant to be disrespectful in any way - it's just the way it is.

In your case, I would recommend that you think long and hard about going. You would be going to a new country, to places you've never been before - with all that entails. While that's not a terrible thing (many people travel to places they've never been), it is certainly not low-stress when this new place is your home for the next 6-8 years. The normal stress of graduate school is nothing to laugh at, and adding this kind of stress on top of it is something you really need to consider. I've seen a lot of people crumble under the stress - it's not pretty.

As you said, you should really think about what you want from your career. The job market for people with advanced physics degrees is not super great. You should ask yourself exactly what this degree is going to do for you. Do you NEED it for the career that you want, or are you doing this because you don't know what to do right now?

On top of that, there is the cost issue. Can you afford graduate school? There are lots of places that will happily take people with a physics background; if they think you need more education, they will send you (and pay for it). If you can't afford it now, are you willing to go into serious debt afterward? (The correct answer is "No.")

If you asked me for advice, I would tell you that you'll do much better (and be much happier) getting a job in industry.